# Can a remote app invoke local Outlook?

Tags: remote-desktop, remoteapp

I have a cloud server on Azure and I connect via Remote Desktop (with gateway).

When connecting, I have only one Remote App. This application allows also to send emails. In a local environment, when sending an email, it opens a new email from Outlook, with some pre-filled text and attachments. I have no mail client on the server, and I don't want to have any, since many different users should be able to use the same server (each one has a different email address and email configuration).

Is there a way to configure the remote server to invoke local email default client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to instantiate a local app from a remote app.

If this server has the RDS role installed and you have valid/activated RDS client access licenses then each user will have their own session on the server when they launch the RemoteApp. As such, you can install Outlook on the server and each user will have their own Outlook profile and will be able to use their own individual email address.

If you don't have the RDS role installed and don't have valid/activated RDS client access licenses and these users are connecting to the server for anything other than remote administration of the server then you are in violation of the EULA.

Comment: This suggestion is applicable if the users work in a RDS environment all the time, what I'm looking for is a mixed environment: all the client applications, included Outlook, are installed on the local computer, and only one app is accessed via Remote Desktop (I have the RDS licenses installed).

Comment: The EULA is applicable whether the users run 1 application or 100 applications from the RDS server. To answer your question more directly; there is no way to instantiate a local app from a remote app. You'll need to install Outlook on the RDSH host.